# Date type in Spring data for Apache Solr

Tags: solr, spring-data-solr

Is there a Solr "date" type representation in Spring data for Solr? I have a requirement of indexing the timestamp/date of a new document indexed. And I'm using Spring Data for Apache Solr. How can I represent Solr "date" type in Spring Data for Solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data allow to use class `java.util.Date` as field type in your class definition.

Code like this should work:

```
public class Clazz {

    @Indexed("date_dt") Date date;

}
```